# Initial content of newly allocated heap memory (VS2010)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

Below is a snippet of a simple VC++ program that is being run on Visual Studio 10 with Thread Building Blocks (open source 4.1) support.

I compiled and ran a program from examples, and was surprised to see the output of new operator from the cout.

```
int main() {
  string str[N] = { string("a"), string("b") };
  for (size_t i = 2; i < N; ++i) str[i] = str[i-1]+str[i-2];
  string &to_scan = str[N-1];
  size_t num_elem = to_scan.size();

  size_t *max = new size_t[num_elem];
  size_t *pos = new size_t[num_elem];
  cout <<"*max : " << *max<< ", "<<"*pos :"<<*pos<<endl;
......
......
```

The cout output is like one below :

*max : 3452816845, *pos : 3452816845

**What surprises me is the same values for max and pos in both cases.**

Is this probably due to some overloading of new operator in the library ?

OR

Is this a bug to be reported ?

OR

Is this just a coincidence ?

Comment: probably my thought of this being a bug is incorrect

Comment: Your thought on your thought on this being a bug being incorrect is correct. This is the default behaviour of the debug version of the heap allocator in MSVC run-time - it fills newly allocated heap memory with `0xCD`, known internally as `_bCleanLandFill` - see [here](http://zeroflag.wordpress.com/2007/05/03/magic-values-on-the-msvcrt-debug-heap/). Btw, the code fragment that you've shown doesn't use TBB at all so your question's title is misleading.

Comment: Since you clearly know you're printing the content of uninitialized memory, I don't understand your question.  Did you expect some particular value?

Comment: http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html

Comment: Nah! I was surprised by same value at both ocassions, and I was thinking TBB in some library is overloading new operator for some purpose not known to me. Thanx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The content of newly allocated space on the heap is undefined, since it will not be initialized by operator new for a standard type. 
The value translates to 0xCDCDCDCD in hex, I guess the complete heap region is filled with this pattern for some reason.

Some more details:

- You allocate two arrays of type size_t on the heap. Since size_t is a
  typedef for unsigned int, opreator new will just allocate space on the heap (like malloc would),
  but will not call any constructor or initialize the memory in any way.
- The allocated arrays are assigned to pointers of type size_t, which will then point
  to the first elementof the arrays.
- The cout statements are printing the content of the memory the pointers point to (since the pointers are dereferenced), which contain whatever was stored there before.